# Classification with pretrained pytorch vgg16 model and its classes

Tags: pytorch, classification, torch, vgg-net, torchvision

I wrote a image vgg classification model with pytorch's pretrained vgg16 model.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import torch
from PIL import Image
import urllib
from skimage.transform import resize
from skimage import io
import yaml

# Downloading imagenet 1000 classes list
file = urllib. request. urlopen("https://gist.githubusercontent.com/yrevar/942d3a0ac09ec9e5eb3a/raw/238f720ff059c1f82f368259d1ca4ffa5dd8f9f5/imagenet1000_clsidx_to_labels.txt")
classes = ''
for f in file:
  classes = classes +  f.decode("utf-8")
classes = yaml.load(classes)

# Downloading pretrained vgg16 model
model = torch.hub.load('pytorch/vision:v0.6.0', 'vgg16', pretrained=True)

print(model)

for param in model.parameters():
    param.requires_grad = False


url, filename = ("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/pytorch/hub/master/dog.jpg", "dog.jpg")

image=io.imread(url)

plt.imshow(image)
plt.show()

# resize to 224x224x3
img = resize(image,(224,224,3))

plt.imshow(img)
plt.show()
# Normalizing input for vgg16
mean = [0.485, 0.456, 0.406]
std = [0.229, 0.224, 0.225]
img1 = mean*img+std
img1 = np.clip(img1,0,1)

img1 = torch.from_numpy(img1).unsqueeze(0)
img1 = img1.permute(0,3,2,1) # batch_size x channels x height x width

model.eval()
pred = model(img1.float())
print(classes[torch.argmax(pred).numpy().tolist()])
```

The code works fine but its outputting wrong classes. I am not sure where I did wrong but If I have to guess it might be the imagenet yaml classes list or at the normalizing input image. Can anyone tell me where I am making the mistakes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are some issues with the image preprocessing. Firstly, the normalisation is calculated as `(value - mean) / std)`, not `value * mean + std`. Secondly, the values should not be clipped to [0, 1], the normalisation purposely shifts the values away from [0, 1]. Secondly, the image as NumPy array has shape *[height, width, 3]*, when you permute the dimensions you swap the height and width dimension, creating a tensor with shape *[batch_size, channels, width, height]*.

```py
img = resize(image,(224,224,3))


# Normalizing input for vgg16
mean = [0.485, 0.456, 0.406]
std = [0.229, 0.224, 0.225]
img1 = (img1 - mean) / std

img1 = torch.from_numpy(img1).unsqueeze(0)
img1 = img1.permute(0, 3, 1, 2) # batch_size x channels x height x width
```

Instead of doing that manually, you can use [`torchvision.transforms`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/torchvision/transforms.html).

```py
from torchvision import transforms

preprocess = transforms.Compose([
    transforms.ToTensor(),
    transforms.Normalize(mean=[0.485, 0.456, 0.406], std=[0.229, 0.224, 0.225])
])

img = resize(image,(224,224,3))
img1 = preprocess(img)
img1 = img1.unsqueeze(0)
```

If you use PIL to load the images, you could also resize the images by adding [`transforms.Resize((224, 224))`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/torchvision/transforms.html#torchvision.transforms.Resize) to the preprocessing pipeline, or you could even add [`transforms.ToPILImage()`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/torchvision/transforms.html#torchvision.transforms.ToPILImage) to first convert the image to a PIL image (`transforms.Resize` requires a PIL image).