# How to do Class Activation Mapping in pytorch vgg16 model?

Tags: tensorflow, image-processing, pytorch, conv-neural-network, torch

I wrote a [pretrained vgg16](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62482336/classification-with-pretrained-pytorch-vgg16-model-and-its-classes) model for image classification and its layers are

```
VGG(
  (features): Sequential(
    (0): Conv2d(3, 64, kernel_size=(3, 3), stride=(1, 1), padding=(1, 1))
    (1): ReLU(inplace=True)
    (2): Conv2d(64, 64, kernel_size=(3, 3), stride=(1, 1), padding=(1, 1))
    (3): ReLU(inplace=True)
    (4): MaxPool2d(kernel_size=2, stride=2, padding=0, dilation=1, ceil_mode=False)
    (5): Conv2d(64, 128, kernel_size=(3, 3), stride=(1, 1), padding=(1, 1))
    (6): ReLU(inplace=True)
    (7): Conv2d(128, 128, kernel_size=(3, 3), stride=(1, 1), padding=(1, 1))
    (8): ReLU(inplace=True)
    (9): MaxPool2d(kernel_size=2, stride=2, padding=0, dilation=1, ceil_mode=False)
    (10): Conv2d(128, 256, kernel_size=(3, 3), stride=(1, 1), padding=(1, 1))
    (11): ReLU(inplace=True)
    (12): Conv2d(256, 256, kernel_size=(3, 3), stride=(1, 1), padding=(1, 1))
    (13): ReLU(inplace=True)
    (14): Conv2d(256, 256, kernel_size=(3, 3), stride=(1, 1), padding=(1, 1))
    (15): ReLU(inplace=True)
    (16): MaxPool2d(kernel_size=2, stride=2, padding=0, dilation=1, ceil_mode=False)
    (17): Conv2d(256, 512, kernel_size=(3, 3), stride=(1, 1), padding=(1, 1))
    (18): ReLU(inplace=True)
    (19): Conv2d(512, 512, kernel_size=(3, 3), stride=(1, 1), padding=(1, 1))
    (20): ReLU(inplace=True)
    (21): Conv2d(512, 512, kernel_size=(3, 3), stride=(1, 1), padding=(1, 1))
    (22): ReLU(inplace=True)
    (23): MaxPool2d(kernel_size=2, stride=2, padding=0, dilation=1, ceil_mode=False)
    (24): Conv2d(512, 512, kernel_size=(3, 3), stride=(1, 1), padding=(1, 1))
    (25): ReLU(inplace=True)
    (26): Conv2d(512, 512, kernel_size=(3, 3), stride=(1, 1), padding=(1, 1))
    (27): ReLU(inplace=True)
    (28): Conv2d(512, 512, kernel_size=(3, 3), stride=(1, 1), padding=(1, 1))
    (29): ReLU(inplace=True)
    (30): MaxPool2d(kernel_size=2, stride=2, padding=0, dilation=1, ceil_mode=False)
  )
  (avgpool): AdaptiveAvgPool2d(output_size=(7, 7))
  (classifier): Sequential(
    (0): Linear(in_features=25088, out_features=4096, bias=True)
    (1): ReLU(inplace=True)
    (2): Dropout(p=0.5, inplace=False)
    (3): Linear(in_features=4096, out_features=4096, bias=True)
    (4): ReLU(inplace=True)
    (5): Dropout(p=0.5, inplace=False)
    (6): Linear(in_features=4096, out_features=1000, bias=True)
  )
)
```

After some initial hick-up its now working fine. I want to use this model for class activation mapping (CAM) for visualizing CNN outputs. I know that in order to do that first we have to get the activations of last convolutional layer in vgg16 then the weight matrix of the last fully connected layer and lastly take the dot product of the two.

First I got the class index for the query image using this code

```
model.eval()
pred = model(img1.float())
class_idx = torch.argmax(pred).detach().numpy().tolist()
classes[class_idx]
```

Then I fetched the input images last convolutional layer activations which is of the size `torch.Size([1, 512, 14, 14])`

```
last_conv_feat = torch.nn.Sequential(*list(model.features)[:30])
pred_a = last_conv_feat(img1.float())
print(pred_a.shape)
```

After this I extracted the weights of the fully connected layers of vgg16 classifier and it has a shape of `torch.Size([1000, 4096])`

```
model.classifier[6].weight.shape
```

From this weight matrix then I recovered the weight parameters for the relevant class index

```
w_idx = model.classifier[6].weight[class_idx] # torch.Size([4096])
```

The problem is the shape of the convolutional activation matrix and the fully connected layer doest match, one is [1, 512, 14, 14] and the other is [4096]. How do I take dot product of these two matrix and get the CAM output?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This particular model isn't suitable for the simple approach you've pointed out. The CAM you refer to are extracted from models that have only one linear layer at the end, preceeded by a global average pooling layer, like this

```
features = MyConvolutions(x)
pooled_features = AveragePool(features)
predictions = Linear(pooled_features)
```

This typically works with ResNet architectures or one of their many derivates. Hence, my recommendation would be that unless there's a specific reason to use VGG you adopt a ResNet architecture.

------- EDIT -------

If you want to go with VGG, there are two options:

1. The easy one: cut off the VGG's last three (linear) layers, replace them by AveragePooling and a single Linear layer and finetune for ImageNet or whatever dataset you are using.
2. Approximate a CAM by converting VGG's last three layers into convolutional layers (i.e. 4096x512x7x7 with no padding and then 4096x4096x1x1 and 1000x4096x1x1), and reorgnise the parameters. This whole thing has only convolutional layers now and you can operate it like a huge convolutional filter. Only problem: It's output is still size 1x1. Therefore, you will need to enlarge your image (try maybe 2x) and then convolve it with the newly created fully-convolutional network. This gives you an approximate CAM.

Comment: Thank you for the reply, If I want to continue with this vgg model with more than one fc layer then how should I proceed?

Comment: @Eka I've edited my question to sketch two possible directions for that.